# Multiwebsite, multiple domain setup Magento 2 after migration

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, migration, magento2

I have migrated a Magento 1 shop to Magento 2. All is working as expected except for the multi website setup. My original M1 installation consisted of 1 website with 2 stores (different domains: .nl and.be), both of them had 2 `storeviews` (different languages NL and EN, NL and FR).
All documentation I can find is showing how to setup the websites and stores in Magento2 and what to alter in `index.php` to get the wanted result on frontend. My problem is that all this documentation provides solutions for showing multiple websites, but my setup consists of 1 website and therefore one website-code ('base'). Also it doesn't explain how the second domain needs to be set up, what do I put in the index-file there? I figure I need to use the store-code instead but I can't get the second domain to work. The main domain is working (because that's 'base').

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I have setup the second domain and created `symlinks` to the main folder for app, var, pub and lib.
- Edited `index.php` in the root of my website in various ways. Below is just one example of many I tried, I'm showing this one because in my head it should be something like this.

  ```
  $params = $_SERVER;

  switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
           case 'spijl-in-stijl.be':
           case 'www.spijl-in-stijl.be':
                $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'spijl-in-stijlbe';
                $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
           break;
           default:
                $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'base';
                $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
  }
  ```
- Created and edited `index.php` in my second domain folder. It's either showing 403 forbidden or it's redirecting me to the main domain.
- Tried using store-codes in stead of websitecodes but it's throwing errors (can't find the requested store)
- Tried editing the `storeviews` on backend by changing the second store setup, it broke the entire website, could only restore it by editing base URL's in the database.
- Edited `.htaccess` in root, added an edited `.htaccess` in second domain

The settings in backend are set properly. All base URL's are set correctly.
It all comes down to the same theory> It would probably work if the website code was different for both domains.

I'm really hoping someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

To run Magento in multi-store mode, you don't really need to create multiple directories. The only exception is that if your hosting provider need separate directories for each domain you host, but for most of the providers, this is not true.

Make sure below configurations was done in your server and magento to run multi store.

**Configure base url:**

Go to **`Magento admin >> Stores >> Configurations`** and then Switch the configuration scope to your corresponding store / website. Then replace the existing configured url with your new url for the corresponding store. This url will be helpful: https://mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-magento-2.html

**Configure .htaccess:**

Add below code to your .htaccess file in your webroot after replacing the values with correct store code and domain name.

```
SetEnvIf Host yourwebsite.com MAGE_RUN_CODE={{YOUR STORE CODE HERE}}
SetEnvIf Host yourwebsite.co.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

Once the above configuration is done, you can remove the changes you made to index.php.

Making changes to .htaccess is also not a very good practice. You can also do this via configuring it in your vhost file.

For Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName yourwebsite.com

            DocumentRoot {{Your webroot}}

            <Directory {{Your webroot}}/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
            </Directory>

            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "store1_code"
            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName yourwebsite.co.uk

                DocumentRoot {{Your webroot}}

                <Directory {{Your webroot}}/>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                </Directory>

                SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "store2_code"
                SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"
</VirtualHost>
```

For Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourwebsite.com
    set $MAGE_ROOT {{Your webroom}};
    set $MAGE_RUN_CODE = store1_code;
    set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE = store;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourwebsite.co.uk
    set $MAGE_ROOT {{Your webroom}};
    set $MAGE_RUN_CODE = store2_code;
    set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE = store;
}
```

Note: The above sample code won't just work with copy and paste, instead you will need to replace the values with your website specific values and copy the necessary configs from here and place it appropriate section of your website / web-server configuration